# Search and sort in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel, I know you can do

```
$users = Post::where('hide', '=', 0)->take(40)->get();
```

to get all Post-objects where hide = 0 and

```
$users = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->take(20)->get();
```

to sort them, but what if I want to do both?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do

```
$users = Post::where('hide', '=', 0)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(20)->get();
```

You can continue to chain methods from [the query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries) after the `where`.

Comment: I see, I thought the :: was some other kind of thing than ->, but I understand the chaining now, thanks!